# Plot a 4 column data as dot plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a matrix in R like following

```
             H520KOR1 H520KOR2 H5202GyPHR1 H5202GyPHR2
ILMN_1702609 5.916239 6.068699    4.910235    4.983025
ILMN_1762631 5.490704 5.454779    4.573977    4.628981
ILMN_2193175 5.730220 5.726268    6.222486    6.273563
ILMN_3310451 4.955594 5.007212    4.423170    4.333526
```

I would like to plot it in the following way

[image: please check plot here]

I drew this picture in powerpoint. I have tried several ways but I am missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I took the first 10 rows from matrix and `dput()`

```
> dput(dat)
structure(c(5.91623892229345, 5.49070424526676, 5.73021963287428, 
4.9555939015656, 7.34200299329158, 4.49057379554289, 5.17555122512255, 
5.6535332613054, 4.96143970172796, 4.4791600551366, 6.06869857120224, 
5.45477925441301, 5.72626774546258, 5.00721151456707, 7.33658261931523, 
4.36058760303988, 5.13085555870237, 5.77523892720755, 4.96844107374241, 
4.41926414134707, 4.91023457951491, 4.57397741940793, 6.22248596066649, 
4.42317017555403, 7.95776070495557, 5.13499805485839, 4.39694778946656, 
4.80648887200906, 4.44717629932841, 5.25723605338541, 4.98302491117088, 
4.62898140897605, 6.27356272326665, 4.33352596469113, 7.9391551372836, 
5.13491596111887, 4.48130179704286, 4.90950199548828, 4.43674075246716, 
5.13877204607323), .Dim = c(10L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("ILMN_1702609", 
"ILMN_1762631", "ILMN_2193175", "ILMN_3310451", "ILMN_1808219", 
"ILMN_1703280", "ILMN_1705466", "ILMN_2135232", "ILMN_1839994", 
"ILMN_3234823"), c("H520KOR1", "H520KOR2", "H5202GyPHR1", "H5202GyPHR2"
)))
```

Would it also be possible to plot the data of two replicates into one line, given a data.frame like  following

```
H520KOR1 control
H520KOR2 control
H5202GyPHR1 treated
H5202GyPHR2 treated
```

which would change the plot to following (Instead of producing individual plots to each row, I feel that it would be better to include all row's information into one plot which would ease the interpretation further). I am just learning the possibilities with ggplot2. This helps in a greatway. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to create a dot plot for each row of data?

Comment: That would be great if we can create for each row. There are 60 rows at most.

Comment: Thank you for not using barplots.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

read.table(text="expression  H520KOR1 H520KOR2 H5202GyPHR1 H5202GyPHR2
ILMN_1702609 5.916239 6.068699    4.910235    4.983025
ILMN_1762631 5.490704 5.454779    4.573977    4.628981
ILMN_2193175 5.730220 5.726268    6.222486    6.273563
ILMN_3310451 4.955594 5.007212    4.423170    4.333526",
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE) -> df
```

For ggplot2, this will work better as a "long" data frame:

```
df <- gather(df, category, value, -expression)
```

You can plot them all on one (though, with 60 of them, the color really won't work):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=category, y=value, color=expression)) +
  geom_point(size=3)  +
  scale_color_discrete(name=NULL) +
  theme(legend.position="top")
```

You can facet them out (again, I'd remove the color if you really do have 60 of them):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=category, y=value, color=expression)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  facet_wrap(~expression) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

We have no idea what styling or labeling requirements you have, so this is the best one can do with the limited info.

If you truly have a matrix vs a data frame, then you need to convert it first and ensure the row names make it to a column. A `dput()` of your data would help enabling us to illustrate how to do that (if needed).

Comment: Thanks a lot.This is really great. After knowing the possibilities with ggplot2, I would like to change the way plot looks. Please check the original thread. I've added some more information with `dput()`